# Changing order of columns

Tags: python

Anyone can help me understand why Inflation appears in the first column and not second and how to change that? I tried different methods and none seems to work. Thank you!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srOtH.png)

I tried using loc but the output was the same.

Comment: Please [don't post images of code/error/textual content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Paste them here as text.

Comment: I'm not going to type your program out to write an answer but looking at the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas-dataframe), you set data plus index when creating the dataframe. Stick monthly_inflation in the data dictionary instead. And post text because images of code are just rude.

Comment: That's not a good dup. A dozen mostly irrelevant answers when really the problem is that  the inflation Series was used as an index when creating the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

To reorder a `DataFrame`, use:

```
inflation_table = inflation_table.reindex(columns=['Year', 'Inflation'])
```

Comment: OP should just fix how the dataframe is created.